# in cake php not set the value when call the function from the ctp file

Tags: cakephp

my authorcontroller file

```
class AuthorController extends AppController {
public function author_quotes_list($author,$page="null")
    {
        $perpage=30;
        $this->commen();
        $author_data=$this->Author->query("select author.*,professions.professions_name from author,professions where author.professions_id=professions.id and author.author_name='$author' and author.status=1  ");
        $this->set('author_data',$author_data);

        //paging
        $count=$quotes_data=$this->Author->query("select count(id) from quotes where author_id=".$author_data[0]['author']['id']." and status=1");
        $limit=$this->paging($page,$count,$perpage);
        $quotes_data=$this->Author->query("select id,quotes from quotes where author_id=".$author_data[0]['author']['id']." and status=1 limit $limit,$perpage");
        //print_r($quotes_data);
        $this->set('quotes_data',$quotes_data);

    }
public function ratings($q_id)
    {
        //echo $quotes_id;
        $tuser=$this->Author->query("select count(id) from user where status=1");
        //print_r($tuser);
        if($tuser==NULL)
        {
            $this->set('tuser',0);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->set('tuser',$tuser[0][0]['count(id)']);
        }
        $vusers=$this->Author->query("select * from totalrate where quoteid=$q_id");
        print_r($vusers);

        if($vusers==NULL)   
        {
            $this->set('vuser',0);
            $this->set('trate',0);
        }
        else
        {

            $this->set('vuser',$vusers[0]['totalrate']['totaluser']);
            $this->set('trate',$vusers[0]['totalrate']['totalrate']);
        }
}
```

my author_quotes_list.ctp file

```
 <?php  $this->requestAction(array('controller' => 'Author', 'action' => 'ratings/'.$quotes['quotes']['id']));?>
                    <div class="star_txt">(<?php echo $trate; ?>/5,  <?php echo $vuser; ?> votes) from <?php echo $tuser; ?> Users</div>
```

when i call the ratings function of author controller is call this function but not set the value of $trate ,$vuser and $tuser value.

Comment: Off-topic, but you don't seem to be using your CakePHP models as they should be used. You should almost *never* have to write your own queries, this will completely skip the functionality of the framework. Please read this chapter [Retrieving your data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html)

Comment: Also, when using the Models as intended, CakePHP offers pagination 'out of the box'. This chapter explains pagination in CakePHP: [Pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html)

Comment: It seems the English language is becoming a bit of a barrier to explain this properly. I've included some links in my comments that contain examples on how to use Models and Pagination in CakePHP. However, these are just suggestions to improve your code and make optimum use of CakePHP. This is not the answer for your direct problem, but at least gives your application a solid 'starting point' for further development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could stand to use some better "CakePHP practices".  First take a more OOP approach and do

```
if (!empty($vusers)) {
```

and secondly if you have a model setup correctly you'd be much better off using a find();

```
$this->Author->Rate->find('first', array('conditions' => ....)));
```

lastly as mentioned above instead of print_r use the cakephp command

```
debug();
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest that in the controller after the if else 
you write : debug($tuser);
and in new line write : debug($vusers);

i think this statement : $this->set('tuser',$tuser[0][0]['count(id)']); is not setting hte variable $tuser because i think $tuser[0][0][count(id)] is not valid index.
so debug function will show you the contents and indices of the array you debug

Answer (score 0):

first of all pay attention to better CakePHP practices. but also look at this page: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html

somewhere in the middle of this page it says:
"You can take full advantage of elements by using requestAction(). The requestAction() function fetches view variables from a controller action and **returns them as an array**."

so your variables are returned by requestAction, they will not be set like standard variables in your view. You have to get them back from requestAction and use them from there something like:

```
<?php $vars =  $this->requestAction(array('controller' => 'Author', 'action' => 'ratings/'.$quotes['quotes']['id']));?>
<?php echo $vars[...] ?>
```